# json jqmodal populate dropdown

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate a dropdown in a jqmodal with different product sizes. I really can't get this to work. Any help appreciated.

My JSON

```
{
    "product": {
        "variants": {
            "3394248": {
                "id": 3394248,
                "code": "19",
                "ean": "19",
                "sku": "19",
                "price": {
                    "price": 19.95,
                    "price_incl": 23.7405,
                    "price_excl": 19.95,
                    "price_old": 0,
                    "price_old_incl": 0,
                    "price_old_excl": 0
                },
                "title": "Maat 95",
                "active": false
            },
            "3376388": {
                "id": 3376388,
                "code": "19",
                "ean": "19",
                "sku": "19",
                "price": {
                    "price": 19.95,
                    "price_incl": 23.7405,
                    "price_excl": 19.95,
                    "price_old": 0,
                    "price_old_incl": 0,
                    "price_old_excl": 0
                },
                "title": "Maat 100",
                "active": true
            }
        },
    }
}
```

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#productVariations').jqm({
  trigger: 'a.ex2trigger'
});

function loadProductVariations(){

var productId = '{{ product.fulltitle }}';
var url = 'http://shop.com/'+productId+'/?format=json';


  $.getJSON(url,function(data){

    var variantHtml = '';

    $.each(data.product.variants, function(index, variants){   
      variantHtml = variantHtml + '<option value="' +variants.id+'</option>';
    });

    $('#productoptions').html(variantHtml);
});
}
```

My html

```
<div class="jqmWindow" id="productVariations">
Even geduld aub... <img src="https://shop.com/com/ajax-loader.gif?1" alt="loading" />
<span id="close">
  <button class="jqmClose">Close</button>
</span>
<br/><br/>
<form class="formProduct" id="product_configure_form" method="post" action="{{ ('cart/add/' ~ product.vid) | url }}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <div id="productoptions">
    <select onchange="document.getElementById('product_configure_form').action = 'http://shop.com/product/variants/2140679/'; document.getElementById('product_configure_form').submit();" id="product_configure_variants" name="variant">

    </select>
  </div>
  <a id="submit" class="button gray" href="#" onclick="$('#product_configure_form').submit(); return false;" title="{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}">{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}</a>
</form>
<span id="message"></span>
```

This is a concept so forgive me the current mistakes in the code! The only thing I need to know is how to populate the dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is not correctly formatted, for one. Missing 2 closing brackets, I have edited it in your original post.

Second, try changing the loop like so:

```
$.each(data.product.variants, function(index, variants){   
variantHtml = variantHtml + '<option value="' +variants.id+'</option>';
});
```

to

```
for (var i in data.product.variants) {
     var v = data.product.variants[i];
     var $opt = $("<option>").text(v.title);
     $("#productoptions select").append($opt);
}
```

Comment: The json is cut out of a really long file, forgot to mention that. Your suggestion doesn't work. Could that be of "3394248": {
that's right after variants in the json?? I don't get any errors in firebug saying "undefined" though. Perhaps I should go for variants.title because that's the actual text for the dropdown. Like this "title": "Maat 95",
Do you have any other solution?

Comment: should be data.product not data.products, edited my answer. See how that works

Comment: Ok found what was wrong... somehow I sleep to little so I missed that it should be data.product.id instead of product.id.